# Download csv with Python scraping button in dynamic web page

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, button, web-scraping, developer-tools

I would like to download a csv from this web page (https://biwenger.as.com/la-liga/players) with python.

There is an option (image attached) that you can download this csv, but I would like to get it programatically.

I don't know how to use *Chrome > Developer Tools > Network* to see where it gets the data. Can anybody help me?

Should I use *Selenium* to perform this actions?

Many thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for in simple Selenium. I did the following.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/driver/path")

driver.get("https://biwenger.as.com/la-liga/players")

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[3]/button/i").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(.,' Export')]").click()
sleep(10)
```